# Identifiy elements in nested array of objects at correct position and show in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json file with the following structure (only example content, the json itself is much larger)

```
   "data": {
  "category 1": {
    "sub category 1": [
      {
        "name": "data 1",
        "soemthing else": "",
      },
      {
        "name": "data 2",
        "soemthing else": "",
      }
    ],
    "sub category 2": [
      {
        "name": "data 3",
        "soemthing else": "",
      },
      {
        "name": "data 4",
        "soemthing else": "",
      }
    ]
  },
  "category 2": [
    {
      "name": "data 5",
      "soemthing else": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "data 6",
      "soemthing else": ""
    }
  ]
```

}

Now i want to show this data within my react application with specific styles, depending on its position in the json. As you can see the json has two different structes: Some of the direct childs (e.g. category 1) has an object containing sub categories, which are arrays itself containing some objects (e.g. data 1). And other direct childs (e.g. category 2) has an array of objects (e.g. data 5).

The desired js function (or directly in jsx - even better) should distinguish between direct child (e.g. category 1), object child of child (e.g. sub category 1) and everything with the key "name". All elements of the json should be dislplayed within my jsx but depending of its position with a specific style.

Im struggling here with the correct ES Functions. If someone can give me a hint or even better a full solution if not that much effort i would be really gratefull. I already tried alot but didnt get a sufficient solution cause of a lack of ES features knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired outcome, you can write a recursive function that iterates over the JSON data and renders the elements with specific styles based on their position in the hierarchy. Here's an example of how you can implement this in React:
`
import React from 'react';

```
const renderData = (data) => {
  // Check if the data is an object
  if (typeof data === 'object' && !Array.isArray(data)) {
    // Iterate over the object keys
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      // Check if the key is "name"
      if (key === 'name') {
        return <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{data[key]}</span>;
      }

      // Check if the value is an array
      if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
        // Render the array elements recursively
        return renderData(data[key]);
      }

      // Render the object child of child recursively
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>{key}</h3>
          {renderData(data[key])}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  // Render the array elements
  return data.map((item) => {
    // Check if the item is an object
    if (typeof item === 'object') {
      // Render the object recursively
      return renderData(item);
    }

    // Render the "name" value
    return <span>{item}</span>;
  });
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const jsonData = {
    "data": {
      "category 1": {
        "sub category 1": [
          {
            "name": "data 1",
            "soemthing else": "",
          },
          {
            "name": "data 2",
            "soemthing else": "",
          }
        ],
        "sub category 2": [
          {
            "name": "data 3",
            "soemthing else": "",
          },
          {
            "name": "data 4",
            "soemthing else": "",
          }
        ]
      },
      "category 2": [
        {
          "name": "data 5",
          "soemthing else": "",
        },
        {
          "name": "data 6",
          "soemthing else": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderData(jsonData.data)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

`
In the above example, the renderData function takes the JSON data as a parameter and recursively iterates over its elements. It checks the type of each element and renders it with the appropriate style based on its position in the hierarchy. The function returns the JSX elements, which are then rendered in the MyComponent component.

Please note that the example assumes that the JSON data structure remains consistent with the provided example. If there are variations in the structure, additional checks and conditions may be required to handle them properly.